# Remove specific object instance from Grid.Children?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a `List<T>` with some `UserControl`s.
On the main window there is a `Grid` and some of the `UserControl`s will be added to `Grid.Children`.
Now I would like to be able to remove specific `UserControl`s from this `Grid` e.g. I would like to do something like this

```
layoutRoot.Children.Remove(controlList[1]);
```

Is this possible?
I only know `FindName()` and `FindResource()` but all the `UserControl`s don't have names so that I can't use these methods :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes I tried `FindName()` by passing the `Name` value of a `UserControl` but the value of each `UserControl` is "".
Maybe I did something wrong. Don't know...

Comment: I mean `layoutRoot.Children.Remove(controlList[1]);`

Comment: -.-' yes thanks it works xD i'm a bit unconcentrated because it's very late :)

Answer (score 1):

just an idea to get you started, if you know the type of your user control, you can use methods like this:

```
static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        var visual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

        child = visual as T;
        if (child == null)
            child = FindVisualChild<T>(visual);
        if (child != null)
            break;
    }
    return child;
}
```