# Programmatically removing an Object from a Grid in Windows Metro

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I have several images being animated inside a `Grid` container and I need to remove them from the `Grid` after the animation ends to save memory.

```
storyboard->Completed += ref new EventHandler<Object^> 
   ([this,birthImage,&index](Object^ sender, Object^ e) {
        mainGrid->Children->IndexOf (myImage,  &index);
        mainGrid->Children->RemoveAt  (index);
    });
```

Unfortunately I cannot follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878009/remove-specific-object-instance-from-grid-children) and use `mainGrid->Chilren->Remove(myImage)` because this method is available only for C# and not for C++/CX

Being forced to use `IndexOf` and then `RemoveAt` causes concurrency problems.

I need a solution to remove an object from a View Hierarchy in C++/CX

Something that in the iOS world could be done with the single:  `[object removeFromSuperView];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class header I've declared

```
private:
   concurrency::reader_writer_lock myLock;
```

And changed the implementation to:

```
storyboard->Completed += ref new EventHandler<Object^> 
   ([this,birthImage](Object^ sender, Object^ e) {
        unsigned int index;
        myLock.lock();
        if (mainGrid->Children->IndexOf (myImage,  &index))
        {
              mainGrid->Children->RemoveAt (index);
        }
        myLock.unlock();
    });
```

Notice the declaration of `unsigned int index` as a local variable to the `lambda` function.